# Changing background-color from separately elements from an array (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    for( var i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ ){
        for( var j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++ ){
            var $class = getPieceName(board[i][j][0])
            $(.$class ????).click(function() {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');     
            });
        }
    }           
});
```

As you can see, I want to change the background color of an element.
The for-loops are needed to get the element, in an array, which the user clicked on.
How to write the variable ($class) as a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If class is a string you can use it like this:

```
$("." + $class).click(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can name your variable then concat it into your selector since its a string not a JQ object.

```
var class = getPieceName(board[i][j][0])
     $('.' + class).click(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

It think all you need is `'.' + $class`

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to apply a class or data-attribute to all your board pieces, like `class="board_piece" data-board-x="1" data-board-y="2"` and then bind the click handler to a selector for that:

```
$('.board_piece').click(function() { $(this).css(...) }
```

You could use the data-board-x and -y coordinates I added to retrieve the actual position within the board inside your click handler.